# How to convert hex chars to byte array in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, hashing

Got sha1 checksum in hexadecimal format(40 characters).
Need help to convert hex chars to byte array in mysql.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as an "array" in MySQL.

Perhaps you want `UNHEX(SHA1("stuff"))` ?  That will provide a 20 bytes, and could be stored, for example, into a `BINARY(20)` column.